# ListFragment and fragment NullPointerException after rotate

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have a simple listFragment:

```
public class ListUtente extends ListFragment{
OnDetailUtenteSelezionato mCallback;
 private String[] utenti = {"Aldo","Giovanni","Giacomo"};
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
public interface OnDetailUtenteSelezionato {
    public void ondetailUtenteSelezionato(int position);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    // set adapter
    setListaUtenti();
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

}

private void setListaUtenti(){

    if(getListAdapter()==null){
        // creo l'adapter
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                utenti);
        setListAdapter(adapter);  
    }
    else
    {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }                       
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView(){
    super.onDestroyView();
    setListAdapter(null);
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detailutente_fragment) != null) {
        getListView().setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        mCallback = (OnDetailUtenteSelezionato) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " devi implementare OnDetailUtenteSelezionato");
    }

}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        mCallback.ondetailUtenteSelezionato(position);

    // Set the item as checked to be highlighted when in two-pane layout
    //getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
}
```

}

a fragment detail:

```
public class DettUtente extends Fragment{
   final static String ARG_UTENTE = "utente";     
    int mUtenteCorrente = 0;
       // onCreateView
       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                mUtenteCorrente = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_UTENTE);
            }
           return inflater.inflate(R.layout.utente_detail,container,false);
       }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }      

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            Bundle args = getArguments();
            if (args != null) {
                // Set article based on argument passed in
                updateUtenteView(args.getInt(ARG_UTENTE));
            } 
                updateUtenteView(mUtenteCorrente);
        }
        public void updateUtenteView(int position) {
            TextView nome = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.detailName);

            nome.setText("fabio");

            mUtenteCorrente = position;
        }
        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putInt(ARG_UTENTE, mUtenteCorrente);
        }
}
```

my activity:

```
public class ActivityUtente extends FragmentActivity implements   ListUtente.OnDetailUtenteSelezionato{
private boolean mDualFragments = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_utente);

    if(findViewById(R.id.framelayout2) != null){

        mDualFragments=true;
        ListUtente lu = new ListUtente();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.framelayout1, lu);
        transaction.commit();
        //nella seconda schermata inserisco il dettaglio
        DettUtente du = new DettUtente();
        FragmentTransaction transaction1 = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction1.add(R.id.framelayout2, du);
        transaction1.commit();           
    }
    else
    {       
            ListUtente lu = new ListUtente();
            //lu.setArguments(0/*getIntent().getExtras()*/);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.framelayout1, lu).commit();                       
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_utente, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void ondetailUtenteSelezionato(int position) {
    DettUtente dettUtente;
    if (mDualFragments) {
        dettUtente = (DettUtente)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detailutente_fragment);

        if (dettUtente != null && dettUtente.isVisible()) {
            dettUtente.updateUtenteView(position);
        } 

    }
    else{
        dettUtente = new DettUtente();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.framelayout1, dettUtente);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();       
    }       
}
```

}

my problem is when i rotate my device. i want to change my view (from vertical to horizzontal etc..) but from horizzontal to vertical i have this error:

```
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.unipg.utente/com.unipg.utente.ActivityUtente}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2187)
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3640)
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:144)
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1216)
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4966)
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786):    at com.unipg.utente.DettUtente.updateUtenteView(DettUtente.java:50)
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786):    at com.unipg.utente.DettUtente.onStart(DettUtente.java:45)
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1484)
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:941)
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1070)
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:1866)
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:568)
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1163)
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5018)
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
            02-27 15:31:34.128: E/AndroidRuntime(10786):    ... 12 more
            02-27 15:31:34.148: W/ActivityManager(278):   Force finishing activity com.unipg.utente/.ActivityUtente
```

Comment: Your TextView "nome" is null after you rotate. Take into account the activity lifecycle and fragment lifecycle and you will understand why. Also, your fragments should not be directly accessing UI elements outside of the fragment.

Comment: on rotate activity is restart. on Create i change view and "nome" is created..